Decomposition of function into products
Given a single variable function $f(x)$, is there a way of decomposing it into the product of a family of function. Something similar to,
$$f(x) = \prod_n p^{a_n}_n(x)$$
I am trying to find the multiplicative counterpart to Fourier or Taylor expansions. Is this useful? What is the nearest thing that comes to mind on seeing this kind of thing? (a friend of mine pointed at the Dyson series)

Well, you can just take the Fourier series of $\operatorname{log}(f(x))$, say $\operatorname{log}(f(x)) = \sum_n a_n p_n(x)$. Then we get $f(x) = \prod_n \operatorname{exp}(p_n(x))^{a_n}$.

See Weierstrass factorization theorem.

(Partial answer, too long for a comment)
Weierstrass factorization theorem is a well-known result which permits to construct representations of entire functions with infinite products.
A lesser known tool, namely the non-standard calculus based on the geometric/multiplicative derivative, defined as $D_* := \exp \circ D \circ \ln$, i.e. $f^*(x) := e^{f'(x)/f(x)}$, where $f'$ denotes the usual additive derivative, permits to study functions with respect to their multiplicative properties. The analog of Taylor series is then given by
$$
f(x) = \prod_{n=0}^\infty \left(f^{[n]}(a)\right)^{\frac{(x-a)^n}{n!}}
$$
where $f^{[n]}$ denotes the $n^\mathrm{th}$ geometric derivative. In the same way, you might consider "multiplicative Laurent products" too. From the inverse operator of the geometric derivative, that is the product integral, you will be able to define analogs of the Fourier transform/series.
